# Ivy configuration problems in new SBT installation

Tags: sbt

New laptop brand new sbt install. When I `show resolvers` it is everything I was expecting with normal urls, when running `show fullResolvers` it reproduces the errors. This is sbt 1.3.13 but I tried some other 1.3 versions and a 0.13 one with similar results. I was able to build a different application using mill so I don't think it is anything to do with the underlying java install.

```
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid host wildcard specification
[error]     at java.net.SocketPermission.init(SocketPermission.java:447)
[error]     at java.net.SocketPermission.<init>(SocketPermission.java:291)
[error]     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1048)
[error]     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1478)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.util.HostUtil.getLocalHostName(HostUtil.java:46)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.<init>(BasicResolver.java:156)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.<init>(AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.java:58)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.<init>(RepositoryResolver.java:65)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver.<init>(URLResolver.java:27)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.<init>(IBiblioResolver.java:83)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1$PluginCapableResolver$1.<init>(ConvertResolver.scala:166)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1.applyOrElse(ConvertResolver.scala:177)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1.applyOrElse(ConvertResolver.scala:154)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$.apply(ConvertResolver.scala:151)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$.$anonfun$resolverChain$1(Ivy.scala:517)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$.resolverChain(Ivy.scala:517)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$.makeChain$1(Ivy.scala:486)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$setResolvers(Ivy.scala:490)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.settings$lzycompute(Ivy.scala:138)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$settings(Ivy.scala:95)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.ivyLockFile$lzycompute(Ivy.scala:200)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.ivyLockFile(Ivy.scala:200)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:209)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:206)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:250)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.moduleDescriptor(Ivy.scala:254)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.dependencyMapping(Ivy.scala:256)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$depMap$5(Defaults.scala:3111)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$depMap$4(Defaults.scala:3111)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Edit: Not every project causes problems, just those that are multiproject builds that that have project dependencies.
Minimal reproduction build.sbt file

```
name := "untitled"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

lazy val projectA = project

lazy val projectB = project.dependsOn(projectA)
```

Comment: Can you please add your build.sbt?

Comment: Happens regardless of the contents of build.sbt, most of the ones I've been using require a bunch of private resources but https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.2.x-new/build.sbt also produces the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: what do you have in `~/.sbt/repositories` and in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: No `~/.sbt/repositories` and `/etc/hosts` has a couple of localhost entries, broadcast host and a docker desktop one. Nothing out of the ordinary

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking your computer name.

Mine had an asterisk in it, and it was causing this exception.
Just
`java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()` in sbt console was failing with the same stack trace.

The issue went away after renaming the computer.